# Is there a way to extract query string from any website?

Tags: python, url, web-scraping, query-string

I am doing an analysis that requires use of query strings.

What tools can I use to extract the query strings of websites that do not show this? For example, Amazon's website is just https://www.amazon.com/ with no further parameters. What can I use to get its query string?

Comment: You mean, what is after the '?' symbol? you can use slicing, splitting , regex etc..

Comment: Not every website uses query strings for passing data from one page to another. Many use a combination of cookies and Javascript.